# Build from context in UnitOfWork pattern on ASP.Net Core

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, repository-pattern, dbcontext, unit-of-work

I had a Repository and UnitOfWork pattern in ASP.Net MVC project and now I want move that to my ASP.Net Core project that get context in UnitOfWork class.

**Context class :**

```
public class LoginContext:DbContext
{

    public LoginContext(DbContextOptions<LoginContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {

    }
    public DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }
    <..other classes..>
}
```

**GenericRepository :**

```
public class GenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    private LoginContext _context;
    private DbSet<TEntity> _entityTable;

    public GenericRepository(LoginContext context)
    {
       _context = context;
       _entityTable = context.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    public virtual async Task<TEntity> GetInfo(int id)
    {
       return await _entityTable.FindAsync(id);
    }

    <... Other Methods ...>
```

**UnitOfWork**

```
public class AccountProvider : IUnitOfWork
{
    private readonly LoginContext loginContext;

    private GenericRepository<Person> personRepository;

    <... and Others ...>
}
```

Also,I have connectionString in my **appsettings.json** :

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
"LoginContext": "Server=.\\MYSQLSERVER;Database=<DatabaseName>;Integrated Security=True;Trusted_Connection=True;"}
```

and ConfigureServices method in **startup.cs** :

```
services.AddDbContext<LoginContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("LoginContext")));
```

Now in controller,I get instance of AccountProvider(UnitOfWork) and want to use it :

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class LoginController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly AccountProvider _accountProvider;

    public LoginController(AccountProvider account)
    {
        _accountProvider = account;
    }
    <... methods ...>
}
```

When I run project and send a request to controller,I get a exception like this:

> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'DataLogin.Context.AccountProvider' while attempting to activate 'MyProject.Controllers.LoginController'

I know that the problem is for get context in controller,and try to review the Internet for UnitOfWork pattern in .Net Core.But don't understand true way for get that.Please guide me..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### To fix your problem:

> You're not registering the AccountProvider (most likely).

That error you're seeing basically means the compiler sees you're trying to use AccountProvider as a service, but you forgot to register it in startup.

```cs
// In startup.cs register a scoped AccountProvider as the concrete class for IUnitOfWork:
services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork, AccountProvider>()
```

This will fix your error. But looking through your code, I can see some design flaws.
You're missing an interface for your generic repository.

### The problem of not using interfaces:

> By not using an IGerericRepository interface you are tightly coupling your Repository to your UnitOfWork class. By doing so, your UnitOfWork class will become almost impossible to test.

My advice would be to create and IRepository class and use that in your UnitOfWork.

```cs
public interface IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    // Code omitted for brevity.
}

public class GenericRepository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    // Code omitted for brevity.
}

public class AccountProvider : IUnitOfWork 
{
    private LoginContext _context;

    // Use the IRepository class
    private IRepository<Person> _personRepository;

    public AccountProvider(LoginContext context) 
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    // Initiate like this
    public IRepository<Person> PersonRepository 
    {
        get
        {
            if (_personRepository == null)
            {
                _personRepository = new GenericRepository<Person>(_context);
            }
            return _personRepository;
        }
    }
}
```

> Then there's the problem in your naming of the UnitOfWork class.

The UnitOfWork class should hold every single possible database context that your application can consume. The only thing you will ever call in controllers is your UnitOfWork class.

Meaning that by calling it AccountProvider, you are suggesting that the only thing this concrete class does are account-related actions. That makes little to no sense because 99% of the time your application persists a lot more data to the database than just Accounts. So I suggest you rename this to something like `UnitOfWork` or `DataAccessLayer`.